# Keyed delegate factories with runtime constructor parameters?

Tags: autofac

Lets say I have the following service and components:

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoWork();
}

public class ServiceA : IService
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public ServiceA(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        //ServiceA DoWork implementation
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IService
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public ServiceB(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        //ServiceB DoWork implementation
    }
}
```

Notice that each component takes a constructor parameter `name`.  Lets also say that `name` is determined at runtime.

I've been going through the AutoFac documentation to try to find a type-safe way to resolve components like this without having to reference the container directly.  If I had only one implementation of `IService` then I could just use a [Delegate Factory](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Delegate-Factories) to pass the runtime parameter to the constructor.  However, I have two implementations, and the one that should be used must also be determined at runtime.  If I didn't have the `name` constructor parameter then I could [register the two components by Key and the resolve using IIndex](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/wiki/Typed-Named-And-Keyed-Services#by-key)

I can't figure out how to do both.  Is there way I can somehow combine the use of Delegate Factories and `IIndex` component resolution?  Or is there another way to register and resolve both components without having to directly reference the container?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you say, your two *individual* requirements are natively supported by AutoFac.

- Runtime resolution of constructor parameters can be implemented using [Parameterized Instantiation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b)
- Resolution of a particular service implementation can be implemented using [Keyed Service Lookup](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#keyed-service-lookup-iindex-x-b)

However, there doesn't appear to be direct support for using these two constructs together. I.e. the following **does not work**:

```
public enum ServiceType
{
    ServiceA,
    ServiceB
}

public class MyComponent
{
    public MyComponent(Func<string, IIndex<ServiceType, IService> factory)
    {
        var service = factory("some_string")[ServiceType.ServiceA];
    }
}
```

My work around for this has always been to **move the resolution of the service to a factory per service implementation**. This then works as follows:

1. Components with a dependency on a specific service implementation take in an AutoFac factory delegate that resolves to the factory specific to the required service implementation
2. In turn, the service factories have a dependency on an AutoFac factory delegate that knows how to create the specific service implementation from the (runtime) constructor parameters of the service
3. This approach uses the native AutoFac constructs and doesn't have any dependencies on AutoFac outside of the container wiring.

Heres a rough-and-ready example. Note the multiple factories could be reduced to a single generic factory - but I've left it as-is for clarity:

**Service implementations**

```
public enum ServiceType
{
    NotSet,
    ServiceA,
    ServiceB
}

public interface IService
{
    string DoWork();
}

public class ServiceA : IService
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public ServiceA(string name)
    {          
        _name = name;
    }

    public string DoWork()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IService
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public ServiceB(string name)
    {           
        _name = name;
    }

    public string DoWork()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**Service factories**

```
public interface IServiceFactory
{
    IService Create(string name);
}

public class ServiceAFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    private readonly Func<string, ServiceA> _factory;

    public ServiceAFactory(Func<string, ServiceA> factory)
    {            
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IService Create(string name)
    {
        return _factory(name);
    }
}

public class ServiceBFactory : IServiceFactory
{
    private readonly Func<string, ServiceB> _factory;

    public ServiceBFactory(Func<string, ServiceB> factory)
    {            
        _factory = factory;
    }

    public IService Create(string name)
    {
        return _factory(name);
    }
}
```

**Service registrations**

```
builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>().As<ServiceA>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>().As<ServiceB>();
builder.RegisterType<ServiceAFactory>().Keyed<IServiceFactory>(ServiceType.ServiceA);
builder.RegisterType<ServiceBFactory>().Keyed<IServiceFactory>(ServiceType.ServiceB);
builder.RegisterType<ComponentWithServiceDependency>().As<ComponentWithServiceDependency>();
```

**Example usage**

```
public class ComponentWithServiceDependency
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public ComponentWithServiceDependency(IIndex<ServiceType, IServiceFactory> serviceFactories)
    {            
        // Resolve the ServiceB service implementation,
        // using the string "test" as its constructor dependency
        _service = serviceFactories[ServiceType.ServiceB].Create("test");
    }

    public string Test()
    {
        return _service.DoWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow nice work around! With the current version of Autofac, you can also do a `builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>();`, so you don't have to define it twice. Don't know if this was possible when you wrote your answer though.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Interface Segregation.

```
public interface IService
{
    void DoWork();
}

public interface IServiceA : IService
{
}

public interface IServiceB : IService
{
}

public class ServiceA : IServiceA
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public ServiceA(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        //ServiceA DoWork implementation
    }
}

public class ServiceB : IServiceB
{
    private readonly string _name;

    public ServiceB(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void DoWork()
    {
        //ServiceB DoWork implementation
    }
}
```

Then, you can inject delegate factories like so:

```
public class ClientA
{
    public ClientA(Func<string, IServiceA> serviceAFactory, Func<string, IServiceB> serviceBFactory)
    {
        this.serviceAFactory = serviceAFactory;
        this.serviceBFactory = serviceBFactory;
    }

    public CreateServices()
    {
        var runTimeName = "runTimeName";
        var serviceA = this.serviceAFactory(runTimeName);
        var serviceB = this.ServiceBFactory(runTimeName);
    }
}
```

Autofac will generate a delegate factory for each interface you register:

```
public class MyModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ServiceA>()
            .As<IService>()
            .As<IServiceA>();

        builder.RegisterType<ServiceB>()
            .As<IService>()
            .As<IServiceB>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is worse than the accepted answer if both services have the same parameters as for 100 services it will require 100 constructor arguments.

Comment: And it is better than the accepted answer if the services have typed arguments. It is cleaner to have a switch and call a specific service factory than have generic interfaces and non-obvious casts.